# Network cost information element

Tags: networking, dnsmasq

Anyone knows how to publish Network cost information element (explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391819.aspx) using dnsmasq or by any other means?

Answer (score 1):

This is for vendors and WiFi-driver hackers. You can use something like 'hostapd' to add this to your hotspot. It is communicated inside the WLAN beacons so one need to knows a thing or two about WiFi drivers.